# CUDA implementation of Softmax

Tags: python, cuda, numba

I am looking to improve the speed of my softmax layer using CUDA. Due to a shortage of examples for python and CUDA, I was hoping to get some suggestions over here. I have set up a naive implementation and looking for advice on the same.

```
@cuda.jit
def softmax(X, w, b):

    m = X.shape[0]

    probs = np.zeros((m, 120))
    startX=cuda.grid(2)
    gridX=cuda.gridDim.x * cuda.blockDim.x;
    for i in range(startX, m):
        X_slice = X[i,:,:,:]
        z = np.dot(X_slice,w).reshape(1, w.shape[-1])
        z_exp = np.exp(z) 
        z_probs = z_exp/np.sum(z_exp) 
        probs[i,:] =z_probs

    A_prev = (X, w, b)
    return probs, A_prev
```

Comment: My advice would be to try running your code and when it inevitably doesn't work come back with a concrete question which you require an answer to. And before doing that I would direct you to [this part](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/cudapysupported.html#numpy-support) of the Numba documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have set up a naive implementation and looking for advice on the same

Ok, let's have a look at your code in the light of [this page](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/cudapysupported.html#numpy-support) of documentation:

```
@cuda.jit
def softmax(X, w, b):

    m = X.shape[0]                                     # OK

    probs = np.zeros((m, 120))                         # Illegal, array creation
    startX=cuda.grid(2)                                # OK
    gridX=cuda.gridDim.x * cuda.blockDim.x;            # OK but unused
    for i in range(startX, m):                         # Illegal, startX is not a scalar
        X_slice = X[i,:,:,:]                           # Illegal, array creation
        z = np.dot(X_slice,w).reshape(1, w.shape[-1])  # Illegal, array method
        z_exp = np.exp(z)                              # Illegal, array method
        z_probs = z_exp/np.sum(z_exp)                  # Illegal, array method
        probs[i,:] =z_probs                            # OK (except probs can't be created in kernel)

    A_prev = (X, w, b)                                 # OK tuples are supported
    return probs, A_prev                               # illegal, kernels can't return anything
```

So basically, your entire code is illegal and can never work. If you want some advice, I refer you to the documentation I linked to:

> For best performance, users should write code such that **each thread is dealing with a single element at a time**

Emphasis mine. CUDA Python programming is more than just adding `@cuda.jit` in front of some code you already have and expecting it to run fast. You need to imagine the element wise code for the complete algorithm and then write code to perform that. For the code above, that probably requires more than one kernel.